# how to convert list to string ignoring other characters in python?

Tags: python

I have a list like `["['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']", '109']` with array,numbers inside a list. 
How do I convert it to the string `"abcd"`?
I have done `out = ' '.join(row)`, which removes commas. I am new to Python.

Comment: Commas are part syntax of list, Not it's values. So it will remove by join.

Comment: thank you for the answer

Answer (score 2):

The first element in the list is string representation of a list and not a list. To make it a list you can eval it like so:

```
from ast import literal_eval

l = ["['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']", '109']
print ''.join(literal_eval(l[0]))
```

Output:

```
abcd
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `ast.literal_eval`. However, you really should not have got your data into this format originally, so I suggest instead going back a step and tackle the root issue.

```
>>> import ast
>>> ''.join(ast.literal_eval("['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']"))
'abcd'
```

Answer (score 1):

A good way of doing this is using the re module.

```
import re
out = ''

for character in list:
    if re.search('[A-Za-z]', character):
        out += character
```

Answer (score 1):

let say `temp = [["a","b","c","d"], 109]`
So in python shell run codes blow:

`str = temp [0]`  // assign array ["a","b","c","d"] to str

`''.join(str)`    // gives you `abcd` as string in output

don't forget this command should be run on python shell !